# lazyload.js - Repeated image issue

Tags: jquery, html, image, jquery-plugins, lazy-loading

I'm using jQuery [lazyload.js](https://appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/) for lazy-loading the product images in an application. But it causes the images to render twice as src attribute and background-image. Please find the below details for more information. Any helps would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
<img class="lazy" data-original="https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7060/6969705425_0905bf6bba_o.jpg" >

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("img.lazy").lazyload();
});
```

[image]

Comment: You tried data-src instead of data-original ?

Comment: Yeah ! It wasn't working. I have end up fixing it by removing the image tag and adding data-original attribute to 'a' tag.